# Haskell tree: data constructor not in scope

Tags: haskell, tree, scope

In a certain program I defined the following data structure:

```
data IntTree = EmptyTree | InternalNode IntTree Int IntTree 
           deriving (show)
```

And also following the function:

```
size :: IntTree -> Int
size Empty         = 1
size (InternalNode IntTree int IntTree) = (size IntTree) + 13 + (size IntTree)
```

However I get the following error (which appears for every IntTree reference):

```
Not in scope data constructor: ´IntTree´
```

What error did I make in my function definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pattern matching on the type name (`IntTree`), instead you should pattern match on the type constructor (`InternalNode`). Something like this should work:

```
size (InternalNode a int b) = (size a) + 13 + (size b)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was a simple missconception.